# Reading System.in multiple times in Java causes IOException?

Tags: java

I am playing around trying to create a little command line game to reinforce some of the things I have learnt in Java over the last few months.

I am trying to create a method called readInput() which returns a String which I can call again and again. The first time it works perfectly, the second time however it causes an IO.Exception. If I remove the statement bisr.close(); it works but was taught to close streams as it is bad practice to leave them open.

Can someone kindly point me in the right direction as I have googled but to no avail.

The method ...

```
private String readInput()
{
    String input = null;
    BufferedReader bisr = null;
    try
    {
        bisr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        input = bisr.readLine();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            bisr.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that closing the `BufferedReader` also automatically closes the `InputStreamReader` which implicitly closes `System.in`.

And the second time you call that method `System.in` is closed, which means you won't be able to read from it.

The "always close it" only really applies to resources that you also opened!

Answer (score 7):

> ***The first time it works perfectly, the second time however it causes an IO.Exception***

`bisr.close()` will also **close the underlying input stream** (in this case `System.in`). This is why consecutive reads will result in an IOException.

> ***If I remove the statement bisr.close(); it works but was taught to close streams as it is bad practice to leave them open***

No problem in keeping `System.in` open for the duration of the execution.

If you don't want to create unnecessarily many objects, you can create the BufferedReader once, and pass that around.

For this particular situation, I would probably just go with

```
private String readInput() {
    return new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Right yes that looks much better and makes sense. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

For System.in it is better to have a global BufferedReader or Scanner you create once.  This is because a BufferedReader and Scanner can read more than one line which it buffers for performance so you could be discarding some lines or parts of lines.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws  InterruptedException {
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    System.out.println("\nread "+readLine());
    // give me time to write more than one line, no problem from a file.
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}

public static String readLine() {
  // can lose input.
  return new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
}
```

if I enter the numbers 1,2,3 etc across the keyword quickly.

```
1

read 1
2
3
4
read 2

5
6
7
read 4

8
9
0
read 7

-
=

read 0
```

If I use a global Scanner object and do the same thing.

```
static final Scanner IN = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("\nread " + readLine());
    // give me time to write more than one line, no problem from a file.
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}

public static String readLine() {
  return IN.nextLine();
}
```

prints

```
1

read 1
2
3
4
read 2

5
6
read 3

7
8

read 4
9

read 5
0

read 6

read 7

read 8

read 9

read 0
```