# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found while using java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've created 2 classes one for the main program and one for the class itself for rectangle, that suppose to create 2 rectangle from input from the user, prints the information of the rectangle and prints the shape of the rectangle with *, but I get this error when I create the second rectangle:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at Rectangle.input(Rectangle.java:74)
at Program.main(Program.java:20)
```

this is the class for the rectangle:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangle {
    // Data Members for rectangle.
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public String color;
    public int xPos;
    public int yPos;

    //  Initialization.. 
    public void init(int width, int height, String color, int xPos, int yPos) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }
    //  Print all Data Members.
    public void printInfo() { 
        System.out.println("Width: " + width + ",Height: " + height
                + ",Color: " + color + ",X position: " + xPos + ",Y position: "
                + yPos);
    }

    //  Setter (width)
    public void setWidth(int width){
        if(width >= 0 ){
            this.width = width;
        }
    }
    //  Getter (width)
    public int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

    //  Setter (height)
    public void setHeight(int height){
        if(height >= 0){
            this.height = height;
        }
    }
    //  Getter (height)
    public int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

    public void starsRectangle(){
        for(int i=0; i<getHeight(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<getWidth(); j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void input(){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter color");
        String inputC = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter width");
        int inputW = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter height");
        int inputH = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter x position");
        int inputXPos = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter y position");
        int inputYpos = s.nextInt();
        setWidth(inputW);
        setHeight(inputH);
        color = inputC;
        xPos = inputXPos;
        yPos = inputYpos;
        s.close();
    }
}
```

this is the class for the the main program:

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(); // Reference1 + object
        rec1.init(5, 3, "BLUE", 90, 50);
        rec1.printInfo();
        rec1.starsRectangle();

        System.out.println("--------");

        rec1.input();
        rec1.starsRectangle();

        System.out.println("--------");

        Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle(); // Reference2 + object

        rec2.input();
        rec2.printInfo();
        rec2.starsRectangle();


    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348377/reading-system-in-multiple-times-in-java-causes-ioexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create 
`Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);` 
either as instance variable or class variable. and you can use it wherever you want in that class. write one close() method that will close scanner stream before exiting the application.

don't create scanner object every time when method is called and close. rather create once and close stream once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 while(s.hasNextLine()){..}
```

to avoid this error.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. Closing the scanner in the input method also closes System.in, therefore when creating a new Scanner for the 2nd rectangle, you can't read from the console anymore.